# Clicks per day is skewed

Tags: bug, statistics, community-promotion-ads

With the delay that happened with activating the [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) on meta sites, something unfortunate happened: the *clicks per day* metric on the stats page is completely skewed, since it's apparently counting clicks since the ad's creation date (around Jan.15), yet the ads actually only went live very recently, 6-8 weeks later.

Is there a way the counter could be reset to be "as of" the *actual* go-live date?

Comment: I sense a missing 'R' in the title.