# Could we see the number of times an ad was actually served?

Tags: feature-request, statistics, community-promotion-ads

Each [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) post links to a stats page, where we get to see a number of "metrics" including:

- Score / number of net votes on the ad post
- Creation date
- Clicks per day ([which is skewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276739/197901)) / total clicks

[image: ad stats include score, creation date and clicks per day]

All but the *clicks per day / total clicks* are already publicly visible on the ad posting itself. Would it be possible to add the number of times an ad was actually served?